# How to remove unnecessary pen tool created path in an illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As I have created the path which hinders me to change color of my arrow. How to remove such path which might allow to change the color of the created path.[image]

Comment: When you make your curve, make sure you have a stroke only, but no fill. Then when you expand, this won't happen.

Comment: You can just select it with direct  (white arrow) or group selection (white arrow plus.) tools and hit delete

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 3 objects in the image

- a triangle filled with black
- a bent rectangle filled with black, maybe an outlined stroke
- no fill, no stroke shape which resembles a half of an egg

Try to ungroup all. Grouping can prevent coloring because the half egg gets color, too. Delete the half egg, it obviously hasn't no function, it's only a remnant. You can reach it via the layers panel or by dragging over the vertical cord.

Answer (score 0):

You are still able to change the color of your arrow. The issue you have is that the "curve" of your arrow is a stroke, and the "head" of your arrow is a fill.

Optionally, you can merge the two elements into a single element, by doing the following.

1.) Select just the curve, then expand the shape: > Object > Expand (Expand both the fill & stroke):

[image]

2.) Now that your stroke was converted tot a fill, select all elements of the arrow together:

[image]

3.) Pathfinder > Unite:

[image]